# How to filtered dataSourceTable that getting firestore streaming data?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

First of all, My purpose is like https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYM1w8emtN8&list=LL&index=13 this tutorial. But They are a little bit different. I want to make it with Firestore.

I created streambuilder and object. Fetch all data from Firebase to my data source table. But My filter is not still working. How can I fix it?

I want to filter all my data when I click the button. And My data source table will upgrade according to the new query.

Notice: I do not want to make a query again on the server side. Because it will be costly for this project. So, I want to filter all my values locally.

Here is my button widget:

```
OutlinedButton(
                                  style: ButtonStyle(
                                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all(RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(2.0) , )),
                                    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Constants.lightblack),





                                  ),

                                    onPressed: () {

                                  setState(() {
                            
                             //       crossfade = !crossfade;

            
                                    
                                    
                                    kasalarim = filtreData!.where((element) => element!.kasa_adi.contains("hat")).toList();






                             


                                  });

                                }, child: Text("Kasa Ekle" )))
```

Streaming: (from Firestore)

StreamBuilder(

```
                        stream: firestore.collection("Users").doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.email).collection("kasalar").snapshots(),


                     builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snap) {






                       kasalarim = snap.data!.docs.map((e) => Kasalar_object.fromMap(e.data() as Map<String, dynamic> )).toList();

                

                            final DataTableSource _all_kasa = MyKasaData(kasalarim);

                            List<dynamic> map = snap.data!.docs;







                      


                



                            //     if (snap.hasError) return Text ('Error = ${snap.error}');

                            if(snap.hasData ){



                              return PaginatedDataTable(
                                sortColumnIndex: 0,
                                sortAscending: sort,



                                columns:  [


                                  DataColumn(label: Text('Kasa Adi'),
                                  onSort: ((columnIndex, ascending) {
                                    sort = !sort;
                                  }),

                                  ),
                                  DataColumn(label: Text('Para Birimi')),
                                  DataColumn(label: Text('Açılıs Bakiyesi')),
                                  DataColumn(label: Text('Oluşturulma Tarihi')),
                                  DataColumn(label: Text('Aktif/Pasif')),
                                  DataColumn(label: Text('İslemler')),

                                ],
                                source: _all_kasa, //MyKasaData(map),

                                columnSpacing: witdh/15,

                              );






    }


                            else{
                              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()); // new Text('No data...');
                            }
                          }),




class MyKasaData extends DataTableSource {


  SideBarController sideBarController = Get.put(SideBarController());


  // List<Kasalar> kasalar = [];

  MyKasaData(this._data);

  final List<Kasalar_object> _data;




/*

*/


  FirebaseFirestore _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;


  DataRow getRow(int index) {
    return DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].kasa_adi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].doviz_cinsi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].acilis_bakiyesi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].olusturulma_tarihi)),
      DataCell(Text(_data[index].aktivite)),
```

And Lastly the main widget's head:

```
 bool sort = true;
  List<Kasalar_object> filtreData = [];

  List<Kasalar_object> kasalarim = [];

   onSortColumn(int columnIndex, bool ascending) {
     if (columnIndex == 0) {
       if (ascending) {
         filtreData!.sort((a, b) => a.kasa_adi!.compareTo(b.kasa_adi));
       } else {
         filtreData!.sort((a, b) => b.kasa_adi!.compareTo(a.kasa_adi));
       }
     }
   }

  //
  //
  //   }
  //

  @override
  void initState() {

  filtreData = kasalarim;

    super.initState();
  }
```

Lastly my object:

```
class Kasalar_object  {
 final String kasa_adi;
 final String doviz_cinsi;
 final String acilis_bakiyesi;
 final String olusturulma_tarihi;
 final  String aktivite;

 Kasalar_object( {required this.kasa_adi , required this.doviz_cinsi, required this.acilis_bakiyesi, required this.olusturulma_tarihi, required this.aktivite});

//     Map<String, dynamic>
  factory Kasalar_object.fromMap( Map<String, dynamic> kasalar_objectim )  {
    return Kasalar_object(

      kasa_adi: kasalar_objectim['kasa_adi'],
      doviz_cinsi: kasalar_objectim['doviz_cinsi'],
      acilis_bakiyesi: kasalar_objectim['acilis_bakiyesi'],
    olusturulma_tarihi: kasalar_objectim['olusturulma_tarihi'],
    aktivite:  kasalar_objectim['aktivite'], ); // );

  }
```